# Login failed for user 'ndt', help me decipher the stack trace please

Tags: asp.net, mysql, connection-string

I am working with someone else's code.
Trying to get it sorted out.
We re-imaged our server and uploaded fresh clean files. 
(identical to the previous ones, only these are not infected)
I also restored the backup I created of the database.

Everything worked before, but now we are having issues.
I have no experience with this type of authentication.
It appears to go through an mdf file before querying the data.

Can't seem to get around the Login failed for user error.

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'ndt'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +187
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +199
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2297
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +34
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +606
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +220
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +502
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +28
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +429
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +512
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +104
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +177
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +118
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +140
  System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +83
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1748
  System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +13
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +149
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +68
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
  NDTCourses.TimeKeeping.WebForm14.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\cflick\Desktop\NDTCourses\NDTCourses\TimeKeeping\declare_time.aspx.cs:264
  System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +13
  System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +45
  System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +98
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4315


<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=TECH-ILL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timeKeep;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="db" connectionString="Data Source=TECH-ILL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timeKeep;Integrated Security=True" />
  <add name="timeKeepConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=TECH-ILL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timeKeep;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This concerns the authentication to the database. Your program tries to log in to the database using user "ndt", and it fails. Check your username and password in your connection string in your Web.config.

Comment: username and password are not contained in the web.config file. I am not sure where they are contained.  I am not familiar with this type of security.

Answer (score 1):

Either the ndt server login no longer exists or the server login is no longer associated with the database user (commonly called an orphaned user).

In the first case, you need to create the database login and then handle the orphaned user.

Orphaned users happen when restoring databases to new or rebuilt servers or when recreating database logins. You can find instructions on fixing this problem at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475.aspx.

Comment: I have the user 'ndt' set up through plesk and I can see the user in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Is the password for the login correct? Have you checked to see if ndt on the database and the ndt login are associated correctly?

Comment: I set the password in plesk for the user ndt, but I cannot seem to find where the password is in the files that actually connect to the db so I cannot tell if they match.  I will update my question with the connectionStrings code from the web.config.